# Show Loading Dialog until webpage fully loads in WebView

Tags: android, webview, dialog

I have a page that loads some data in a webview.

```
webView.loadUrl();
```

How can I have a dialog with "loading..." in it show until the page finishes loading in the webview?

Do I need to get the network speed? Is there a `FINISHEDLOADING()` method I can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `WebViewClient` callbacks. There are `OnPageFinished()` callback and lots of other useful things.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
       ......some code here..
   }
 });
```

So all you need to do is show progress right after `webview.loadUrl()` method and dismiss it in `onPageFinished()` callback method.